Яндекс Карты api v 3 перетаскивание двумя пальцами на мобильных и тач-девайсах
Как сделать масштабирование (pinchZoom) и перетаскивание (drag) карты на мобильном / тач-устройстве только двумя и более пальцами? А если участвует только один палец, то только разрешить скроллить блок с картой вниз-вверх (т.е. просто пролистывание блока с картой, карта остается неподвижной). Ответы для api 2 не подходят. Просто отключение drag в behaviors не помогает - тогда целый блок с картой перестает двигаться любым количество пальцев.
Попробовал скрипт с определением количества касаний и наложением pointer-events на карту. Но перестает работать pinchZoom. Подозреваю, что с количеством касаний не все так просто и логика там может быть сложнее.
Условный код:
const mapEl = document.getElementById('map');

// Убираем временно взаимодействие с картой при загрузке
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // Определяем, что тач-девайс / мобильное устройство
    if ( ('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) && mapEl) {
        mapEl.firstElementChild.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }
});

// Определяем количество нажатий и добавляем / убираем взаимодействие с картой

mapEl.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
    // Со старта нажатия разрешаем
    mapEl.firstElementChild.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
});

mapEl.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
    if (e.touches.length >= 2) {
        mapEl.firstElementChild.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    } else {
        mapEl.firstElementChild.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }
});

mapEl.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
    mapEl.firstElementChild.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
});

Может кто-то уже решил эту задачу? Или есть более простое решение?

Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1584615/ymaps3-js-api-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-touch-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8 Увы без ответа
